# JQuery Tablesorter clear table information

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I've created a jquery table that from time to time needs to be cleared and the re-populated, my clear method is this:

```
//Clear table content before repopulating values
$('#table tr:gt(0)').remove();
```

Now i'm trying to use tablesorter to sort a specific column, but my problem is that when I enable the tablesorter:

```
//Initialize tablesorter
$("table").tablesorter();
```

The table clearing method is not working anymore, it just keeps adding the new data with the old data, creating a lot of repeated information.

Please help

Answer (score 16):

To update tablesorter, an "update" needs to be triggered before it will update its cache

```
$('table').trigger('update');
```

You could also use the built-in function to clear the table

```
$.tablesorter.clearTableBody( table );
```

Here is the code combined from [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/eY8uH/333/)

```
var $table = $('table');

// use built in clear function
$.tablesorter.clearTableBody( $table[0] );
$table
    .append('<tr><td>george</td><td>papard</td><td>68</td><td>19.99</td><td>55%</td><td>+3</td></tr>')
    .trigger('update');
```

Comment: how can I preserve the sorting preferences that way?

Comment: @apostolov Try out my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html), an [update event](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#update) can be flagged to resort the contents on update.

Comment: Thank you very much. This was the ONLY thing that would work for me

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why it shouldn't be working. Is it working without the tablesorter plugin?

Why are calling `tablesorter()` on `table` but try to delete rows from `#table`? Typo?

Try logging the jQuery objects for `$('#table')`, `$('#table tr')` and `$('#table tr:gt(0)')` and see if everything is correct there.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could make it working was to regenerate whole table (remove it and then create  again).

```
$(".resultTablePlaceholder").html('').html('<table id="resultTable">...</table>');
$("#resultTable").tablesorter();
```

Answer (score 0):

Cause:

Its because when we add any data in table it trigger buildCache() method and save table data in cache variable, but when you delete data from table its not going to make any change in cache variable.

when you sort data than it will clear table and append cached data to table so there is deleted data also present.

Solution:

you can modify onselectstart() function or mousedown event in tablesorter.js

```
//here tb_35 = id of table 
cache = buildCache($('#tb_35')[0]);
```